# Indexing object in for loop, retaining info on click

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have javascript, including an ajax call, that takes an empty form input and uses what the user types to query for a json object. It successfully returns matching objects and displays them in a datalist.

This all works fine, but now I'm trying to make sure that when they click a list option, I get certain fields from ONLY that selected option so I can eventually post them to a form.

When an option is clicked I'm getting the value I want in my console (`console.log(searchResult[i]._source.frm.grp.Name)`) but it gives me every one from the previous objects, where I just want the data from the one clicked.

I think this could have to do with the fact that I'm doing that function in the for loop or it my have something to do with my indexing using [i] but I can't pinpoint it.

How can I get this to only affect the values of the indexed object that is clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//input event handler
$('#productInput').on('input', function(){
    if($(this).val() === ''){
       return;
    }else{

       const searchResult = $(this).val(); 

       $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
                data: {
                    search_result:searchResult
                },
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                type: "POST", 
                success: function(response){
                    $('#returnedProducts').empty();
                    let searchResult = response.hits.hits;

                    for(let i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
                        $("#returnedProducts").append("<option value=" + searchResult[i]._source.category + ">" + searchResult[i]._source.category + "</option>");

                        //Issue starts here//
                        $("#productInput").on('input', function(){
                            var val = this.val = this.value;
                            if($('#returnedProducts option').filter(function(){
                                return this.value === val;
                            }).length){
                                document.getElementById("grpName").value = searchResult[i]._source.frm.grp.grp_name;
                                document.getElementById("grpNum").value = searchResult[i]._source.frm.grp.grp_code; 
                            }
                        })   
                    }
                }
            });
    }

});
</script>

<form>
<input id="grpName">
<input id="grpNum">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this but here is what I understand:

- all your code here is already wrapped in a listener on `'input'` event, there shouldn't be any need to add another listener, especially to work on the same property (`.val()` or `.value` seem to refer to the same thing, right?)
- you have 3 cases: one when `#productInput` is empty, one when it's a partial match (suggestions), and you're adding one when it's a perfect match
- to "export" this code to that upper level, you're going to need a higher access to what you currently have as `searchResult` (not the `const` one, the `let` one)
- for the same purpose you're going to have a way of linking an `<option>` with an element in your `searchResult` (like adding an arbitrary param `srindex` containing the index of the element in `searchResult`)

Eventually, your top `if` block should look like:

```
let _this = $(this);
let foundOption;
if (_this.val() === '') {
  return;
} else if (foundOption = $('#returnedProducts option').find((option) => {
  return option.srindex === _this.val();
})) {
  console.log(searchResult[foundOption.srindex].blahblah);
} else {
  $.ajax(...);
}
```

A note:

- using `.find()` is generally faster and can't be slower than `.filter()`, since the former stops on the first matching element, whereas the latter walks the whole array anyway (since it returns *all* matching elements, and here you have *zero or one* to be found) *spoiler post-update: we're not talking about Array.prototype.find, we're about jQuery.find, but shhh, I don't know it yet!*
- I'm not sure `option.srindex` works as-is, maybe it's something like `option.getAttribute('srindex')` *spoiler post-update: it doesn't work as-is*

**UPDATE** (solution after a long chat and many tries)

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function () {
  let _this = $(this);
  let foundOption;
  let searchResult = [];
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;
  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ((foundOption = $('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector)).length) {
    $("#grpName").val(searchResult[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.frm.grp.grp_name);
    $("#grpNum").val(searchResult[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.frm.grp.grp_code);
  } else {
    $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
      data: {
        search_result: _this.val()
      },
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      type: "POST", 
      success: function (response) {
        $("#returnedProducts").empty();
        for(let i = 0; i < response.hits.hits.length; i++) {
          $("#returnedProducts").append(
            `<option srindex="${i}" value="${searchResult[i].cat}" />"`
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: So just to clarify my end of it: The first listener (on('input') is checking the users input and sending that via ajax to an endpoint query, then success returns matches for each keystroke. This works. Now I'm just making sure if they click one of the given options that it fills the form values, which is why I had the secondary input event. Does that make sense?

Comment: So I added this and changed my ```const searchResult``` to ```var searchResult = option.srindex``` and now it says 'i' is undefined, I'm assuming in my iterator?

Comment: "making sure if they click one of the given options that it fills the form values": then it's not a listener on `#productInput` that you need, do you?

Comment: I was under the impression that click events wouldn't work with datalist options

Comment: `'input'` is not `'click'`, and although I haven't used these in a long time (thanks, AngularJS) you don't want to check your `option`s: you want to check the `select` they're bound to, that's the one who'll give you the _selected_ `option`.

Comment: So I should put a listener in my datalist, since I'm not using select?

Comment: Ow OK, sorry, misunderstood that. Never used a `datalist`, but since it seems quite static, no: keep the idea of listening to the `option`. About "if they click one of the given options that it fills the form values": you mean filling `#productInput` value?

Comment: No that's already filled properly if they select an option but I have an external form where I'm pulling the ID of each input to fill them on click. I'll update my question quickly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179051/discussion-between-stock-overflaw-and-whisou138).

Comment: One issue I found here though: The original functionality is that the ajax would post on each keystroke. My JSON object comes from that ajax being posted. So if they type C it posts C, if they type CA it posts CA. I don't have a static object.

Comment: That shouldn't be any issue: `$('#productInput').on('input', function () { ...data: { search_result: _this.val() } });` with `_this` being the jQuery-wrapped input and `.val()` being fetched on each `'input'` event. You don't have that "dynamic" behavior?